# how to extract a particular value in a text file using regex and save the extracted one in another file?

Tags: python, regex

have a text file many values how to extract a particular part from it and arrange it in orderwise in another text file

some part of text file :

```
{
"number": "acd162",
"password": "pass1425-*",
"Type": "phone"

}
{
"number": "bcd119",
"password": "pass1234- ",
"Type": "phone"

}
{
"number": "abc123",
"password": "pass0*++",
"Type": "phone"

{
"number": "ahwc1286",
"password": "pass*-+",
"Type": "phone"

}
```

output i need :

need password column of all in another text file as

```
1="pass1425-"
2="pass1234- "
3="pass0*++"
4="pass*-+"
```

tried this :

```
"password":.* "\w+"
```

but couldn't figure out how should i extract them and give order wise value assign to them 1,2,3,4,5.....

Comment: Please _don't_ use regex to parse JSON!  Look into using a JSON parser instead.  Speaking of which, Python ships with a native `json` library which is quite powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text file isn't JSON:

```
import re

data = '''
{
"number": "acd162",
"password": "pass1425-*",
"Type": "phone"

}
{
"number": "bcd119",
"password": "pass1234- ",
"Type": "phone"

}
{
"number": "abc123",
"password": "pass0*++",
"Type": "phone"

{
"number": "ahwc1286",
"password": "pass*-+",
"Type": "phone"

}
'''

for i, p in enumerate(re.findall(r'"password":[^"]*"(.*?)"', data), 1):
    print('{}="{}"'.format(i, p))
```

Prints:

```
1="pass1425-*"
2="pass1234- "
3="pass0*++"
4="pass*-+"
```

If it is JSON:

```
import json

data = '''
[{
"number": "acd162",
"password": "pass1425-*",
"Type": "phone"

},
{
"number": "bcd119",
"password": "pass1234- ",
"Type": "phone"

},
{
"number": "abc123",
"password": "pass0*++",
"Type": "phone"
},
{
"number": "ahwc1286",
"password": "pass*-+",
"Type": "phone"
}]
'''

for i, d in enumerate(json.loads(data), 1):
    print('{}="{}"'.format(i, d['password']))
```

Prints:

```
1="pass1425-*"
2="pass1234- "
3="pass0*++"
4="pass*-+"
```